# Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).?

Tags: objective-c, sdwebimage

In my application, i want to load the image from server at that time,this error showing on my console.

Here is my some of code.

```
@try
    {
        if((NSNull *)[[responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"banner"] != [NSNull null])
        {
            if([[[responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"banner"] length] > 0)
            {
                NSString *mainBannerimage = [[responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"mainbanner"];
                NSString *bannerImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"demo.world.com/contest/banners/%@", mainBannerimage];

                NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:bannerImageURL];
                [cell.listBanner sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL
                                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profilepic_bg"]];
            }
            else
            {
                //ivUserImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profilepic_bg"];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {

    }
```

Plz help me.

**Answer**

in my code i missed http://

Comment: 1) Which line?  2) don't use try/catch in Objective-C code.

Comment: @Avi, removed it but not working.

Comment: You have to tell us which line is causing the exception.  Enable the exception breakpoint, if necessary.

Comment: @Avi. thius line  [cell.listBanner sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL
                                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profilepic_bg"]];

Comment: What is happened if u try use another url? And try add scheme as http:// before URL

Comment: What u see in debug mode? Who is Nil?

Comment: `cell.listBanner` is exist?

Comment: @Bimawa. yes .i tried but not working.

Comment: `cell.listBanner` exist when u catch exception? Just `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` catched when memory is dealoced offen. Or u wrong configure `cell` object.

Comment: @Bimawa. i removed try and catch block. and checked cell objects after that i am printing my cell.listBanner.it showing like this "The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104410/discussion-between-bimawa-and-mangi-reddy).